# Java: Find the first 10 words in a string. What is the most efficient algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to write some code which retrieves the first 10 words of a string.

The best algorithm I can imagine is to split the string by space and take the first 10 elements. However, this is not bery efficient as the string could be very long.

Is there any better algorithm in Java that can achieve this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, just split on the first 10 spaces and ignore the rest of the string.

Comment: Is not efficient was regular expression are not very efficient (they are simple to use which is usually more important)  If you have a long string you have to read at least the start of the string to find the end of the tenth word.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`String.split(String regex,int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with a specific limit - don't invoke the regex rule more then 11 times.

It will create a `String[]` object, with 10 first elements are seperate words, and the last element contain words where the rule was not checked on yet [so it will not split the rest of the string]

Answer (score 6):

Try [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html):

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("i am a very very long String");
     for(int i = 0; i < 10 && st.hasMoreTokens(); i++) {
         System.out.println(st.nextToken());
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a limit using `String.split()`.

From the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Answer (score 3):

Just scan from left to right:

```
static String[] first10Words(String s) {
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    int pos = 0;
    while (l.size() < 10) {
        int newPos = s.indexOf(' ', pos);
        if (newPos == -1) {
            l.add(s.substring(pos));
            break;
        }
        l.add(s.substring(pos, newPos));
        pos = newPos + 1;
    }
    return l.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: This could lead to a memory leak, since the original big String will be gc'ed only, when the 10 substrings are as well.

Comment: I don't see how this could cause a memory leak, can you elaborate?

Comment: This solution is much more complicated than the others.

Comment: That's true, but it's much faster that split. StringTokenizer isn't much slower, admittedly.

Comment: @Daniel: Sure, i think this one: http://www.precisejava.com/javaperf/j2se/StringAndStringBuffer.htm is one of more thorough explanations.

Comment: @Rekin I don't see what you're getting at, how does the answer relate to StringBuffer or interning?

Comment: @Daniel: Each time you call `s.substring(pos)` a new reference to the old, big string is created. These references is prohibiting the original string from being gc'ed

Comment: @Rekin true, but [StringTokenizer.nextToken does this too](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.java.html), and [so does String.split](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html). So all of these solutions have the same memory behavior. Could be fixed with `new String(s.substring(pos, newPos))`.

Comment: @Daniel: Wow, i never really checked it and always assumed it would be more though through implementation. Surely you now have my +1.

Answer (score 3):

With Regex ?

```
public String getFirst10Words(String arg) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\S]+\\s*){1,10}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(arg);
    matcher.find();
    return matcher.group();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to java but I've done this one who is more basic:

```
public void getSummary () {
    int count=0;
    int position=0;
    for ( count = 0 ; count < 10 ; count++ )
    {
        position = yourString.indexOf(" ", position+1);
    }
    System.out.println(yourString.substring(0,position)+"...");
}
```